# Running installed python module directly from terminal

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, terminal, pip

I've just installed the tvrenamr module by running the following command:

```
pip install tvrenamr
```

No, when I try to use it by running it from terminal as specified here in the documentation:https://tvrenamr.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html

I get the following error:

```
No command 'tvr' found, did you mean:
 Command 'tr' from package 'coreutils' (main)
 Command 'tar' from package 'tar' (main)
 Command 'tv' from package 'treeviewx' (universe)
 Command 'tdr' from package 'devtodo' (universe)
 Command 'tor' from package 'tor' (universe)
tvr: command not found
```

Please help me understand why the module is not running from the terminal and how to run it.

Edit: After uninstalling and reinstalling it, I got the following message:

```
Downloading/unpacking tvrenamr
  Downloading tvrenamr-3.6.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (384kB): 384kB downloaded
Installing collected packages: tvrenamr
Compiling /tmp/pip-build-yZsRKH/tvrenamr/tvrenamr/vendor/yaml/__init__.py ...
  File "/tmp/pip-build-yZsRKH/tvrenamr/tvrenamr/vendor/yaml/__init__.py", line 284
    class YAMLObject(metaclass=YAMLObjectMetaclass):
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Successfully installed tvrenamr
Cleaning up...
```

Comment: hmmm it works fine on my machine did you install it in a virtualenv?

Comment: Is the directory that you installed `tvr` into in your PATH environment variable?

Comment: Did you get any error messages when running the `pip` command? Did you turn on/off a virtualenv afterwards? It seems like there's something wrong during / after the install.

Comment: I just ran that command directly from the terminal without interfering with anything or setting up any venv.

Comment: i'll suggest you uninstall it and install it again...try to read the output of `pip` to see if it outputs any messages that might lead you to the problem

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you need to `import tvrenamr`.

Answer (score -1):

## Running Python from a terminal

you should be able to run from the terminal with

```
machine:user$ python tvr file
```

Comment: python: can't open file 'tvr': [Errno 2] No such file or directory                                  It shows the above error message.

Comment: Did you mean `python -m tvr file`?

Comment: @tdelaney - /usr/bin/python: No module named tvr
It shows this message. Even though I've installed it and it runs from python shell.